# I'm Not able to Get Languages in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**view : Lang_view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CodeIgniter Internationalization Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        form_open('lang');

        ?>
        <select name='language' onchange='javascript:this:form:submit();'>
        <?php

        $lang = array('english'=>'English','french'=>'French','german'=>'German');

        foreach($lang as $key => $val){

            if($key == $language){
            echo "<option value='".$key."' selected>".$val."</option>";}
                    else
            echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$val."</option>";
        }

        ?>
         </select>
<?php form_close(); echo $msg ;?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller : Lang_controller**

class Lang_controller Extends CI_Controller{

```
    public function index(){

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $language = $this->input->post('language');

        if($language == 'french')
            $this->lang->load('french_lang','french');
        else if ($language == 'german'){
            $this->lang->load('german_lang','german');
        }
        else
            $this->lang->load('english_lang','english');

     $data = array(
           'msg' =>  $this->lang->line('msg'),
            'language' =>  $language
        );

        $this->load->view('lang_view',$data);


    }


}
```

I have created three different language folder in application/language. Still when i click any other language i'm not able to generate the output except for english.

Comment: if($key == $language){ } here  $language come from ?

Comment: from controller

Answer (score 0):

In here you need to change the default language.

```
//change system default language dynamically

$language = $this->input->post('language');
$this->config->set_item('language', $language );
```

Answer (score 0):

to start a form in codeigniter you need to write `echo` before form_open

`<?php echo form_open('lang') ?>`